# Why do I get "Type okhttp3.Call does not have type parameters" when using Retrofit2?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, retrofit2, okhttp

I am trying to follow this tutorial for Retrofit2 [Getting Started and Create an Android Client](https://futurestud.io/blog/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client).

The imports are fine

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0-beta3'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
```

and I can follow the tutorial fine except for one thing. I am trying to create the `GitHubService Interface` and I run into two problems: The `Call<V>` says that it doesn't take any type parameters and I am also unsure where to put the `Contributor` class since it's according to the tutorial only declared as `static`, does that mean it's nested somewhere?

```
import okhttp3.Call;
import retrofit2.http.GET;
import retrofit2.http.Path;

public interface GitHubClient {
    @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
    Call<List<Contributor>> contributors(
        @Path("owner") String owner,
        @Path("repo") String repo
    );
}

static class Contributor {
    String login;
    int contributions;
}
```

I have the Contributor class in a separate file and have it as public.
Also, the Call class does not import automatically in Android Studio, I have to select it manually, but it's the only Call I got (except for Androids phone api)

Please help me with why I get this errors, from what I can see there is no one around with the same thing so I am missing something fundamental.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Accordingly to the compile time error you are getting you did import `Call` from the wrong package. Please, check your import and be sure that you have

```
import retrofit2.Call;
```

everything Retrofit related import should be from the package `retrofit2`.

On the other hand

```
 Call contributors(
```

it can't guess what you want to return. A `Contributor` ? a `List<Contributor>` maybe? E.g.

```
public interface GitHubClient {
    @GET("/repos/{owner}/{repo}/contributors")
    Call<List<Contributor>> contributors(
        @Path("owner") String owner,
        @Path("repo") String repo
    );
}
```

Comment: I changed it to the exact thing you written (same as tutorial) and NOW I get the error as described above

Comment: There is no `Call` available in retrofit :S If I select Call and press `alt+enter` I can only select to create new classes etc.

Comment: Do I need to import older Retrofit version? If I `compile` both `com.squareup.retrofit` and `com.squareup.retrofit2` then I can import `retrofit.Call`. Is this what I'm suppose to do?

Comment: no you don't need that. You just need retrofit2 and you have to import [this](https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit/src/main/java/retrofit2/Call.java)

Comment: I did edit the answer. If you have still problem, please post more code

Comment: This is weird... I can't get the import with autofill, but if I write it manually it pops up :S

Comment: Yes it's working when I manually write the import `import retrofit2.Call;`, which you provided. Thank you! :)